# Centering stacked up absolute element + centering flex column vertically to window height

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, absolute

Im trying to code a training website and I have 2 issues that I don't know how to fix.

1st: Those 3 buttons (`.side-buttons`) on the left side should be in the middle (vertically) of the window height.

2nd: There is a `.headline` div that contains an .svg element and a heading that should be stacked up and positioned in the middle of that .svg element. I thought about making the .svg element `position: relative;` and the give the heading the `position: absolute;`, but I don't know how to center it when the height isn't defined. How do I do this? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

How it looks like right now (don't look at the font sizes, I'll correct that later)

[image: How it looks like right now (don't look at the font sizes, I'll correct that later)]

How it should look like:

[image]

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.welcome-screen {
  background-color: Lightblue;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 3.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.side-buttons {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.side-buttons img {
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  display: block;
}
.side-buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.headline {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.headline img {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.headline h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;

}
nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}
.headline {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-section {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- header section -->
  <!-- side buttons -->
  <div class="side-buttons">
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="pinterest icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="facebook icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="twitter icon">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end of side buttons -->
  
<section class="welcome-screen">
  <div class="headline">
    <h1>The time is</h1>
    <img src="css/assets/now.svg" alt="now">
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="">intro</a>
    <a href="">gallery</a>
    <a href="">services</a>
    <a href="">contact</a>
  </nav>
</section>
<!-- end of header section -->

<section class="intro-section">

</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `body` `display: flex;`, and set `.welcome-screen` to `flex-grow: 1;`, and your icons on the left will be centered vertically. Then set `flex-wrap: wrap;` on `body` and `width: 100%;` on `.intro-section` for that section to display underneath `.welcome-screen`. Then add `position: relative` to `.headline` and add `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to your `h1` and it will center over the svg.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.welcome-screen {
  background-color: Lightblue;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 3.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.side-buttons {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.side-buttons img {
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  display: block;
}
.side-buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.headline {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.headline img {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.headline h1 {
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
nav {
  text-align: center;

}
nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}
.headline {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-section {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- header section -->
  <!-- side buttons -->
  <div class="side-buttons">
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="pinterest icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="facebook icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="twitter icon">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end of side buttons -->
  
<section class="welcome-screen">
  <div class="headline">
    <h1>The time is</h1>
    <img src="css/assets/now.svg" alt="now">
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="">intro</a>
    <a href="">gallery</a>
    <a href="">services</a>
    <a href="">contact</a>
  </nav>
</section>
<!-- end of header section -->

<section class="intro-section">

</section>

</body>
```

Comment: Well, .side-buttons are now correctly positioned, but the text is still not in the middle of the .svg element. Another thing that I've noticed after your fix is that the next section (`.intro-section` at the bottom of the page) disappeared. It's probably because of the `display: flex;` added to the body, but when I add `width: 100%;` to `.intro-section` (that should break the line, right?) it shrinks everything and displays the last section on the right side of the page instead of placing it under (just like the normal section).

Comment: Praise the almighty Michael Coker! He knows all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

change `position` in `img` with `h1`

```
.headline img {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.headline h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
```